# $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, proove that the sum of the maximum of each row is less than $n\|A\|_1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

I'm quite sure this is true, but I'm having trouble in finding a proof for $\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$. I already found it for $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$. Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, such that:

1. Each element $a_{ij}$ of $A$ satisfies; $a_{ij}\leq 1$.
2. Each row has one, and only one, maximum element.
3. There is one, and only one, column which maximizes the column sum.

Then $\sum_{i=1}^n \max\limits_{1 \leq j \leq n} |a_{ij}|<n \|A\|_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$||A||_1 = \sup^{}_{||v||_1=1} ||Av||_1 \geq ||A(\mathbf1 *\frac{1}{n})||_1 = \frac{1}{n} ||A\mathbf1||_1  = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i} \sum_{j} |a_{ij}| \geq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i} \max_{j} |a_{ij}|$

$ \Leftrightarrow n ||A||_1  \geq \sum_{i} \max_{j} |a_{ij}|$

Recall $||A||_1 := \sup^{}_{||v||_1=1} ||Av||_1$ and that $||\cdots||_1$ satisfies all the norm-properties. Then, ($\mathbf{1}$ denotes the vector full of $n$ ones) first inequality follows per definition of supremum and because $||\mathbf{1}\frac{1}{n}||_1 = 1$. Then follows the absolute homogenity of the norm and that the sum of row absolute value components is bigger than any absolute value of component in that row, especially the max one.